# Docker dpage/pgAdmin - permission denied /var/lib/pgadmin/storage

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, pgadmin, docker-volume

i have a dpage/pgadmin:latest Docker container running on an Ubuntu 20.04.

```sh
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.8

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8

docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

Now i want to manually save my backups from my database created with pgadmin to another location.
The backups created with pgadmin are stored in `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage`. So i add this path to my docker volumes in my `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_dat:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - pgadmin_share:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage
```

When i now start the container i get this error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: The user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory.
```

This error occurs because the directory in my volume got `root:root` as owner and not `5050:5050` like mentioned here:
[pgAdmin Container Deployment](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#mapped-files-and-directories)

When i change the permissions on my volume with `sudo chown -R 5050:5050 <pgadmin_share>` and `sudo chmod -R u+rwx` the error disappears and pgAdmin is available.

When i create a backup i have to set the permissions again on the automatically created subdiretory (username of the pgadmin user).

Is there a problem with the nested volume, because i mounted already `pgadmin_dat:/var/lib/pgadmin` ?

I'm curious about how i can solve this better.

I would be happy about any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a local environment, you should set in your directory `sudo chmod 777 -R pgadmin_dat/`. It's going to be solving all you's future problems. Otherwise, if you need more security, set `sudo chmod 5050 -R pgadmin_dat/`, it will your **pgadmin_dat** folder available to write.
So, you should do set the same way to each folder in local machine, no in container, that you need to read/write.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your reply. But this is not a more elegant way, which i ask for.

_When i change the permissions on my volume with sudo chown -R 5050:5050 <pgadmin_share> and sudo chmod -R u+rwx the error disappears and pgAdmin is available._

_When i create a backup i have to set the permissions again on the automatically created subdiretory (username of the pgadmin user)._

I already mentioned that i set the correct permissions, but they dissapear after i created a new dump within pgAdmin.